# Confusion about Flow error wrt Filter function

Tags: javascript, flowtype, reducers

In Javascript I've written code for a reducer to handle the adding & removing of strings from an Array.  This code works fine:

```
const taskId: string = action.payload;
let taskIds: ?Array<string> = state.selectedTaskIds;

if (!taskIds) {
  taskIds = [taskId];
} else if (taskIds.includes(taskId)) {
  if (taskIds.length === 1) {
    taskIds = null;
  } else {
    const idx = taskIds.indexOf(taskId);
    taskIds = [...taskIds.slice(0, idx), ...taskIds.slice(idx +1, taskIds.length)];
    // DNW: taskIds = taskIds.filter((selTaskId: ?string) => selTaskId !== taskId);
  }
} else {
  taskIds.push(taskId);
}
```

What doesn't work is the commented out line prefixed with "DNW" that is supposed to accomplish what the 2 lines of code above it do.  The Flow error message I get is:

> Missing type annotation for `T`. `T` is a type parameter declared in 
>   array type [1] and was implicitly instantiated at  call of method
>   `filter` [2].Flow(InferError)

I've tried several things but couldn't resolve it, which is why I used the other approach.  But I am most curious what this error message is telling me and how to resolve it.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1414

Comment: Interesting read.  I don't quite understand it all other than `filter` seems to have some issues with `Flow`.  I'm just happy that my "old school" approach works.

Comment: What version of Flow are you using? Your code seems to work with v0.117.0. [(Try Flow)](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEA3W8AuUDOBrAksAXPBqjAJYB2A5gNwBQoksCyMamuwGhA-AIIwwoATwA8xMlQB8dWqQBm8ABQBCdNjwYAlPADeteG3Wd4AXngBtNRwC6dAL7wQEDAnlKrGgHQVIAV1AYih7Amtp6Bm5B7F4QIFSoABamJmYAjGH6BoYcGKbw5L4QEHQGDk4uupkGAPTVYAD25MTwpMAAHnnBGN7koG0A8nJRRpolWbVdeeaeM12eGBCkYCCKAAwANC3tmpsznnMLSyutHQDUqZtzsfEJmrZV2Rqd0ZyecqQQqCAwioouEAAVF48cQUSjaEySIhOIFGeDKFKPEJjOy0MrOBDhJHdAAOvgwCWGHFGaKAA)

Comment: To clarify, I'm not saying you need to upgrade. Just need to know what version you're working with to help debug. In general, the error refers to Flow not being able to determine what the type of the array is (i.e., the `T` in `Array<T>`). In your case, Flow should be able to figure it out since you've annotated `taskIds`. Happy to help figure out why it can't in the version of Flow you're using.

Comment: I just ran `npm flow --version` and it said I'm using 6.11.3   Is this possible?

Comment: If you have flow configured normally (as the docs describe), you should be able to run `npm run flow -- version` (with the space) to get the version of flow you're running. It looks like the command you ran returns the version of `npm` and not flow.